# Why is implementing NGRX failing on an Null Injector error?

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have imported @ngrx/store in my app.module as shown here:

```
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { reducers } from './ngrx';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  ],
  imports: [
    StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, {})

  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: []
})
export class AppModule {}
```

When I try to use the store in my component as shown here, I get the error shown below:

```
constructor(
    private store:Store<{heroReducers}>
  ) {}

ERROR Error [NullInjectorError]: R3InjectorError(Standalone[_HomeComponent])[StateObservable -> StateObservable -> StateObservable -> StateObservable]:
```

NullInjectorError: No provider for StateObservable!
at NullInjector.get (/home/keith/kkw/programming/angular/pizza/client/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:5682:27)
at R3Injector.get (/home/keith/kkw/programming/angular/pizza/client/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:6125:33)
at R3Injector.get (/home/keith/kkw/programming/angular/pizza/client/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:6125:33)
at R3Injector.get (/home/keith/kkw/programming/angular/pizza/client/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:6125:33)
at R3Injector.get (/home/keith/kkw/programming/angular/pizza/client/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:6125:33)
at ChainedInjector.get (/home/keith/kkw/programming/angular/pizza/client/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:15424:36)
at lookupTokenUsingModuleInjector (/home/keith/kkw/programming/angular/pizza/client/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:4193:39)
at getOrCreateInjectable (/home/keith/kkw/programming/angular/pizza/client/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:4241:12)
at ɵɵdirectiveInject (/home/keith/kkw/programming/angular/pizza/client/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:12042:19)
at Module.ɵɵinject (/home/keith/kkw/programming/angular/pizza/client/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:998:42) {
ngTempTokenPath: null,
ngTokenPath: [
'StateObservable',
'StateObservable',
'StateObservable',
'StateObservable'
]
}

Reducers are registered here (./ngrx/index.ts):

```
import { ActionReducerMap } from "@ngrx/store";
import { HeroReducers } from "../home/hero/hero.reducers";

export interface State {};

export const reducers: ActionReducerMap <State> = {
    heroReducers:HeroReducers
}
```

I have used NGRX in precisely this manner in numerous applications. I don't know if the error is due to Angular 17's incompatibility with the latest NGRX.

Comment: I assume you are trying to inject store into a service that is `provideIn: 'root'`. is that the thing?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to import in this way

```
...
export class Component1Component implements OnInit {
  demo: Observable<Demo[]>;

  constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) { // <--- changed here!
    this.demo = store.select('heroReducers'); // <--- changed here!
  }
  ...
}
```

Here is a working stackblitz on angular17 which you can use as reference and identify where the problem might have occoured.

[forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngrx-demo-angular-fbdwdr?file=src%2Fpolyfills.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fcomponent1%2Fcomponent1.component.ts,src%2Findex.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.state.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fmodal%2Fdemo.modal.ts)

Also please try to replicate the issue and share back with the full reproducible code on the question and share back the stackblitz, if you are not able to resolve with this solution!